# Create a shortcut to file in Google Drive API PHP Client v2

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

As per [Single-parenting behavior changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-single-parent) in Google Drive API, beginning Sept. 30, 2020, you will no longer be able to place a file in multiple parent folders. Now we should [Create a shortcut to a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts) instead.

Is it possible to create shortcut to the file with [Google Drive PHP Client v2](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) or anyhow simple with PHP.

I have tryed:

```
$file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName('Shortcut Name');
$file->setParents([$parent_id]);
$file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut');
$shortcut = $drive->files->create($file, [
  'shortcutDetails' => [
      'targetId' => $file_id
  ]
]);
```

I'm getting `unknown parameter: 'shortcutDetails'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to create new shortcut using googleapis for php.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

In this case, I would like to propose to use `setShortcutDetails()` in your script. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName('Shortcut Name');
$file->setParents([$parent_id]);
$file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut');

$shortcutDetails = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileShortcutDetails();
$shortcutDetails->setTargetId($file_id);
$file->setShortcutDetails($shortcutDetails);

$createdFile = $service->files->create($file);
```

- Please set `$parent_id` and `$file_id`.

#### References:

- [google-api-php-client-services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services)
- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)